# How to select count of distinct key based on indicator in another column?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a table which is like this:

```
Geo_Key   Var1 Var2..Var50
123        1    0  .. 1
524        0    1  .. 1
323        1    1  .. 1
```

Where Var1-Var50 represents 50 columns having value 1/0.

I want to select count of distinct Geo_Key for each column(var1-var50), when its value is=1.
So Results would be like:

```
Var1 50
Var2 60
....
...
Var50 10
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?  This isn't a code generating service; we're here to help solve programming problems.

Comment: Tried anything like `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN X = 1 THEN Y ELSE NULL END)`?

Comment: I know the solution, I edited the question to remove it from -ve. I am unable to post questions!

Answer (score 0):

Since your variables are binary( especially 0/1) in nature, you can also try summing each column up. The sum would give you the count of each variable with value = 1.

Or, you can try it using proc freq. Pleae check the following link

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi25/25/btu/25p069.pdf

Comment: ok. I think i got it. I will need to remove the duplicate keys before summing up.